# JavaCC lexical error on any type of whitespace

Tags: whitespace, token, skip, javacc

I cleary have the unicode whitespace characters defined in my SKIP token like so:

```
    SKIP {
" "
| "\r"
| "\n"
| "\t"

}
```

However, when I run Java CC it parses all the tokens fine until I hit any of the above mentioning white space characters and it throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" prjct1.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 25.  Encountered: "\r" (13), after : "Random:Word:Here"
```

So as you can see it runs fine until it hits the "\r". I get the same error with " ", "\n", and "\t". Any thoughts? thanks

Comment: In your grammar file is there a colon between SKIP and the left curly brace?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a colon between the SKIP and your bracket.

SKIP: {
    " "
|   "foo"
|   "bar"
}

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Check your quotes. Are they neutral quotes such as " or left/right double  quotes”?

I had double quotes, after making them neutral quote, this error was gone.

Comment: This should be a comment to the OP question as it does not atempt to answer it