# JavaCC lexer doesn't work as expected (whitespace not ignored)

Tags: java, parsing, javacc

I'm trying to implement a parser for the example file listed below. I'd like to recognize quoted strings with `'+'` between them as a single token. So I created a jj file, but it doesn't match such strings. I was under the impression that JavaCC is supposed to match the longest possible match for each token spec. But that doesn't seem to be case for me.

What am I doing wrong here? Why isn't my `<STRING>` token matching the `'+'` even though it's specified in there? Why is whitespace not being ignored?

```
options {
  TOKEN_FACTORY = "Token";
}

PARSER_BEGIN(Parser)

package com.example.parser;

public class Parser {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {

      ParserTokenManager manager = new ParserTokenManager(new SimpleCharStream(Parser.class.getResourceAsStream("example")));
      Token token = manager.getNextToken();
      while (token != null && token.kind != ParserConstants.EOF) {
          System.out.println(token.toString() + "[" + token.kind + "]");
          token = manager.getNextToken();
      }

      Parser parser = new Parser(Parser.class.getResourceAsStream("example"));
      parser.start();
  }

}

PARSER_END(Parser)

// WHITE SPACE
<DEFAULT, IN_STRING_KEYWORD>
SKIP :
{
  " " // <-- skipping spaces
| "\t"
| "\n"
| "\r"
| "\f"
}

// TOKENS
TOKEN :
{
< KEYWORD1 : "keyword1" > : IN_STRING_KEYWORD
}

<IN_STRING_KEYWORD>
TOKEN : {<STRING : <CONCAT_STRING> | <UNQUOTED_STRING> > : DEFAULT 
| <#CONCAT_STRING : <QUOTED_STRING> ("+" <QUOTED_STRING>)+ >
// <-- CONCAT_STRING never matches   "+" part when input is "'smth' +", because whitespace is not ignored!?
| <#QUOTED_STRING : <SINGLEQUOTED_STRING> | <DOUBLEQUOTED_STRING> >
| <#SINGLEQUOTED_STRING : "'" (~["'"])* "'" >
| <#DOUBLEQUOTED_STRING : 
    "\""
      (
        (~["\"", "\\"]) |
        ("\\" ["n", "t", "\"", "\\"])
      )* 
    "\""
  >
| <#UNQUOTED_STRING : (~[" ","\t", ";", "{", "}", "/", "*", "'", "\"", "\n", "\r"] | "/" ~["/", "*"] | "*" ~["/"])+ >
}

void start() :
{}
{
  (<KEYWORD1><STRING>";")+ <EOF>
}
```

Here's an example file that should get parsed:

```
keyword1 "foo" + ' bar';
```

I'd like to match the argument of the first `keyword1` as a single `<STRING>` token.

Current output:

```
keyword1[6]
Exception in thread "main" com.example.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 15.  Encountered: " " (32), after : "\"foo\""
    at com.example.parser.ParserTokenManager.getNextToken(ParserTokenManager.java:616)
    at com.example.parser.Parser.main(Parser.java:12)
```

I'm using JavaCC 5.0.

Comment: It appears that this is a duplicate of an [unanswered question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800493/javacc-lexical-error-on-any-type-of-whitespace). Would still appreciate an answer. Or a workaround if this is a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`STRING` is expanding to the longest sequence that can be matched, which is `"foo"` as the error indicates. The space after the closing double quote is not part of the definition of the private token `CONCAT_STRING`. Skip tokens do not apply within the definition of other tokens, so you must incorporate the space directly into the definition, on either side of the `+`.

As an aside, I recommend have a final token definition like so:

```
<each-state-in-which-the-empty-string-cannot-be-recognized>
TOKEN : {
    < ILLEGAL : ~[] >
}
```

This prevents `TokenMgrError`s from being thrown and makes debugging a bit easier.

Comment: Are you saying that whenever a new token is defined I should not expect whitespace to be handled automatically in it through SKIP? What is then the purpose of SKIP if I cannot take advantage of it in my productions... Can you refer me to the part of JavaCC documentation which states what you are claiming?

Comment: @predi: That's right, a skip token does not apply inside the definition of other tokens. The purpose of a skip token is to define tokens that should be ignored when matching BNF rules (between other tokens, effectively, but not within other tokens). However, you can incorporate your skip token in the definition of other tokens, just as you can with any other token. For example, give your skip token a name, like `WS`. Then redefine `CONCAT_STRING` as `... (<WS>)? ("+" (<WS> ...)+`.

Comment: Oops, that should be `... (<WS>)? ("+" (<WS>)? ...)+`. Forgot some meta characters.

Comment: Well.. Now that I think about it. It kinda makes sense that only whitespace around "top-level" tokens gets skipped. After all other whitespace might be significant as it is in my case, when inside quotes (I even posted an example of this). JavaCC FAQ 3.10 implies that SKIP may or may not be applied. But there's no mention of when anywhere. I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: Predi:  It's best not to think in terms of "top-level" tokens.  All tokens are at the same level. The names for "private regular expressions" (the ones with the #s) are really just macros.

The rules for choosing whether a skipped token definition is applied are the same as the rules for regular token and are covered earlier in the FAQ.

Comment: @Theodore: yes, I understand this now. It occurred to me when I realized SKIP is also a token, not some global setting for token behavior. At the time I used this term because when I removed hashes from private regexes (making them regular tokens) I expected this to work, but it didn't. Hence "top-level" tokens.

Comment: You can use non private tokens (i.e. ones whose names have no #) as macros too.  I'd forgotten that.  But it's still a macro.

Comment: Private tokens are only useful for defining tokens (or subtokens) outside the context of a lexer state. Which is a bit silly, since the token production always has a qualifying lexer state, whether explicit or implicit. You could pretend private tokens don't exist and just add the lexer state <CANT_TOUCH_THIS>, so long as no other token production can cause the lexer to enter that state.